# Excel 2007 - Prevent same data entry in cell, as in row above

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel sheet which allows user input in a set format, i.e. Column C is for Product number and column H is for fault category.

I am wanting to know if it possible to **prevent** the user inputting the same values in C2 and H2, if they already exist in C1 and H1.

Please note, that this is not possible with data validation, as that looks for unique values in a column - I don't have any issue with duplicate values across two rows, as long as the duplicates do not exist in both columns C & H, on the next row down.

I am wanting to ensure the users use one row if there are multiple issues with a product, but they all relate to the same fault category.

I am not great with VBA, so you're help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add this VB to the worksheet module it should work...

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Row > 1 And Target.Column = 8 And Target.Rows.Count = 1 And Target.Columns.Count = 1 Then

    'Search Down
    If Target.Offset(1, -5).Value <> "" Then
        r = Target.Offset(0, -5).End(xlDown).Row
        Do
            If Cells(r, 3).Value & Cells(r, 8).Value = Target.Offset(0, -5).Value & Target.Value Then
                MsgBox ("Duplicate Data detected below")
                Application.EnableEvents = False
                Target.Value = ""
                Application.EnableEvents = True
                Exit Do
            End If
            r = r - 1
        Loop Until Target.Row = r
    End If

    'Search Up
    r = 1
    Do
        If Target.Offset(-r, -5).Value & Target.Offset(-r, 0).Value = Target.Offset(0, -5).Value & Target.Value Then
            MsgBox ("Duplicate Data detected above")
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            Target.Value = ""
            Application.EnableEvents = True
            Exit Do
        End If
        r = r + 1
    Loop Until Target.Row = r


End If

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Aeneas, I have inputted your code, but it doesn't seem to work. I should add, that the column 8 has a drop down list, and is protected by a password. Is this maybe the reason it doesn't work? Thanks.

Comment: You need to be more specific than just saying "it doesn't work". What are the errors/issues?

Comment: Apologies, after inputting your code, i can still input the same values into two rows, one above another. i.e. C1 = "test" H1 = "Dirty" and C2 = "test", H2 = "Dirty". Ideally, this code should prevent this from happening.

Comment: The code excludes the first row as I assumed this would be column names. I've updated now to include first row

Comment: Apologies for this Aeneas, i may be making a silly mistake somewhere. I have uploaded the excel workbook to onedrive here - https://1drv.ms/x/s!Akn8Uf5lYAQ_xTXLeGWv9sD3CtYb . Thanks for your help again.

Comment: Sorry I am unable to download documents where I am. Do you have macros enabled and did you add the code to the right sheet module?

Comment: Hi Aeneas, yeah i have applied it to the correct module, and macros should be enabled.

Comment: I would suggest putting a break point on the first line of code and see if it gets hit when you update a cell on the sheet. If it does step through the code to see what's going wrong.

Comment: Hi Aeneas, unfortunately i am still at a loss with this. I think it may be due to the fact that column H has a data validation list. The link above, is still active.

Comment: Selecting a value from a drop down validation list should still trigger the WorkSheet_Change event. Can you attach a screen shot of your vba window with the code showing?

Comment: You can find the screenshot here https://1drv.ms/i/s!Akn8Uf5lYAQ_xTa60voC1GRFGVx6 Thanks Aeneas

Comment: I was hoping you would include the Project Properties window as I believe you have the code in a general module sheet rather than the Sheet object which has the events associated with the sheet

Comment: I have added a screen shot to the answer. Hopefully this shows you where to put the code

Comment: Apologies i had the code in the general module, instead of the worksheet object. I have tested it now, and although the error appears, i think i may have described my intentions incorrectly. 
The code at the moment prevents the user from entering the same value in the row below, in either column C or H. I want it to to prevent the user inputting the same value in column H, if the same product number is inputted in column C (when the row above relates to the same product, and the same fault category)

Comment: In other words, the user can have two different issues with the same product (Column C), they just cannot use up two rows to describe the same fault category (Column H) relating to that same product.
I hope this makes sense.
Apologies once again

Comment: See updated code. Please note it will only check when Col H is changed and only the rows above not below

Comment: That's it man! Is it not possible to check above and below? Thanks

Comment: Hi Aeneas, is it possible for the code to ignore a duplicate if there is a row with other data between the referenced duplicate. In other words, if row ten has data relating to set 1, row eleven has data relating to set 2, and then row twelve has data relating to set 1 again, can the program ignore the duplicate in this case? As at the moment, the program compares duplicates all the way up the column. If this is not possible, don't worry about it. Thanks.

Comment: The code for what you are now asking for is a lot simpler than what I've already provided. You just need to check the above and below rows and no looping is needed.

Comment: Hi Aeneas, that's me got it working. If i ever needed to change the source column from 8 to 7, would i just update the following part to; 
If Target.Row > 1 And Target.Column = 7

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading your request correctly this **can** be done with Cell Validation:

Apply the following data validation custom formula to the range in both columns C and H:

`=COUNTIFS($H1:$H2,H1,$C1:$C2,C1)=1`

Obviously it won't work in previous versions of Excel that haven't got the `SUMIFS` function.